# Is there a way to programmatically create linked contact?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, abaddressbook

My App needs to save some attributes to the AddressBook, particularly set new URLs for some Contacts. This works well, unless user enables connection to other storages, like Facebook.

If my App tries to save URL to a record, that was just exposed from Facebook, operation ends with an error:

> Error Domain=ABAddressBookErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (ABAddressBookErrorDomain error 0.)"

(again, for other records from default storage it's not an issue)

When I try to modify Facebook entry in my Contacts in native UI, actually it creates a linked record. I want to do the same in my app programmatically. Is it possible?

Comment: hi @Nick Entin, have you got any answer?, I have same issue.

Comment: Hi @SAMIRRATHOD, unfortunately, not. Had to inform users how to workaround, if error is reported

Comment: also covered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40568549/saving-contact-address-to-unified-contact-results-in-cnerrordomain-error-500/53741002#53741002 but no known answer